# How we can bind event inside jquery plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins

I need to bind click event for a anchor tag which is created dynamically.

Example:

```
$.fn.ccfn = function(){
$(".alreadyavailabledom").click(function(){
   $("<a class="dynamicallycreated"></a>");
})
//i am trying like below, but not working

$(".dynamicallycreated").click(function(){
alert("not getting alert why?")
})

}
```

It is written as a plugin code, i tried with on, live etc. Not working.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Event binding on dynamically created elements?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/203198/event-binding-on-dynamically-created-elements)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [event delegation](https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/)

```
$(document).on('click','.dynamicallycreated',function(){
    alert("not getting alert why?")
})
```

or bind the click when creating element

```
$.fn.ccfn = function () {
    $(".alreadyavailabledom").click(function () {
        $('<a>', {
            html: "anchor",
            class: "dynamicallycreated",
            click: function () {
                alert("clicked anchor");
            }
        }).appendTo('#myElement');
    })
}
```

Comment: Did you try this. This is very close, but not working.

Comment: @raj what does not working mean? in what way is it not working? why is it not working?

Answer (score 1):

you should use [***event delegation***](https://api.jquery.com/on/) for that

```
$(document).on("click",".alreadyavailabledom",function(){
   //some operation
});
```

It helps you to attach handlers for the future elements